# Create post with WordPress JSON API Plugin when not logged as ADMIN

Tags: wordpress, json-api, wordpress-json-api

I have recently started working with WordPress & had my first task using JSON API. Now I know that after getting nonce from get_nonce method, I can create post but it is only possible if I am logged in also as an admin.

My question is: How to create post using JSON API when you aren't logged in in the WP Admin Panel?

I am receiving the data from another server in JSON format and using that I want to create a post, but due the nonce factor I can't create post if I am not logged in.

Comment: XMLRPC works fine but i am getting data in json format ? is it appropriate to use XMLRPC when the data you are receiving is in JSON format ?

Comment: Well, in my case I hate XMLRPC because most of the site attacks on my sites are made by XMLRPC... So if you want to try the JSON API you can install https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/... first you need to [authenticate](http://wp-api.org/guides/authentication.html) then you can [create the post](http://wp-api.org/#posts_create-a-post)... 
You can read the post https://codeable.io/community/how-to-import-json-into-wordpress/ and in the last section they talk about the security (nonce)